# How to deploy WAR of Maven Project to JBoss server 6 or 7 from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

In the run configurations, when we make the goals like => `clean install jboss:hard-deploy` , it works with jboss 4 and 5 but not with 6 and 7 !!
Do you have any idea

Comment: the log:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project myproject: Deployment failed and was rolled back. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: And have you tried with `-e` switch?

Comment: i don't know how do that , can you explain more please

Comment: `clean install jboss:hard-deploy -e`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have this in your POM file:-

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>{your jboss version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                <username>{your username}</username>
                <password>{your passwprd}</password>
                <jbossHome>{jboss home}</jbossHome>
                <fileName>{path to war}</fileName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Create a maven run configuration for your project in eclipse for 
`jboss-as:deploy`.
Run the configuration.

Comment: FWIW if you're deploying to local host none of the configuration here is needed.